# MATLAB: an efficient function that can group the unique numbers from a Vector

Tags: matlab, vector, unique, cell

I'm looking for an efficient MATLAB function which is able to transform a vector to a cell with group of unique numbers

e.g

from

```
a=[1 1 5 5 5 2 1 1 1 2 2 6 6 6 8 8 8 8]
```

to

```
a={[1 1] [5 5 5] [2] [1 1 1] [2 2] [6 6 6] [8 8 8 8]}
```

My previous approach was to locate the changing points before running within a loop:

e.g.

```
change_pts = a-[0,a(1:length(a)-1)];
for i=find(ans~=0)
   % codes here
end
```

But it's obviously not an optimised solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a vectorized solution using the functions [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) and [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) like so:

```
a = mat2cell(a, 1, diff([0 find([(diff(a) ~= 0) 1])]));
```

This works by first locating where the values change and marking the ends of sequences of equal numbers with a 1. It then finds the indices of all the ones and computes the spans between these indices (i.e. the counts for each sequence of equal numbers). These counts are then used by [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to break the vector up into a cell array.